# How do I remove common elements from two lists?

Tags: python, list, punctuation

I have two lists such as the examples below (in reality, `a` is longer) and I would like to remove all common elements, in this case the punctuation given in list `punctuation`.

```
a = [['A', 'man,', 'view,', 'becomes', 'mankind', ';', 'mankind', 'member', 'comical', 'family', 'Intelligences', '.'],['Jeans', 'lengthen', 'legs', ',', 'hug', 'hips', ',', 'turn', 'heads', '.']]
punctuation = ['(', ')', '?', ':', ';', ',', '.', '!', '/', '"', "'"]
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is a community where you post some of the code or things you have tried, what have you tried so far?  We are glad to help, what have you tried though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> filter(lambda e: e not in punctuation, chain(*a))
['A', 'man,', 'view,', 'becomes', 'mankind', 'mankind', 'member', 'comical', 'family', 'Intelligences', 'Jeans', 'lengthen', 'legs', 'hug', 'hips', 'turn', 'heads']
```

Or, if you want to maintain you sublist structure:

```
>>> [filter(lambda e: e not in punctuation, sub) for sub in a]
[['A', 'man,', 'view,', 'becomes', 'mankind', 'mankind', 'member', 'comical', 'family', 'Intelligences'], ['Jeans', 'lengthen', 'legs', 'hug', 'hips', 'turn', 'heads']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a set of words to remove and test containment item by item if you need to preserve order.

```
cleaned = [word for word in words if word not in blacklist]
```

Answer (score 0):

**When the order is not important:**

You can do a `set()` operation on it, but first you have to flatten the nested list `a` (taken from [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python#952952)):

```
b = [item for sublist in a for item in sublist]
cleaned = list(set(b) - set(punctuation))
```

`cleaned` is a list that looks like `['A', 'hug', 'heads', 'family', 'Intelligences', 'becomes', 'Jeans', 'lengthen', 'member', 'turn', 'mankind', 'view,', 'legs', 'man,', 'hips', 'comical']`

**When the order is important:**

Simply a list comprehension, which is probably slower

```
cleaned = [x for x in b if x not in punctuation]
```

`cleaned` looks like `['A', 'man,', 'view,', 'becomes', 'mankind', 'mankind', 'member', 'comical', 'family', 'Intelligences', 'Jeans', 'lengthen', 'legs', 'hug', 'hips', 'turn', 'heads']`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but the list order might change.

```
[list(set(sublist)-set(punctuation)) for sublist in a]
```

Using sets, you can remove the punctuation entries, and cast the result to a list again. Use list comprehension to do it for each sublist in the list.

---

If keeping the order is important, you can do this:

```
[[x for x in sublist if not (x in punctuation)] for sublist in a]
```